# annotate-models: Nothing annotated!

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

My situation:

1. I have added the gem annotate-models (1.0.4) to my rails project.
2. Ran "bundle install". The gem is listed when I do "bundle list".
3. I generated a simple model using "rails generate model ..."
4. I executed: "rake db:migrate"
5. I executed: "annotate"

The result:
6. "annotate" returned "Nothing annotated!".
7. My model class remains without annotations.

Any idea as to what might be going wrong?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Apologies. I don't why this is, but I created the model Object in question in the rails console and saved an example to the db. Then, I re-ran "annotate" and the model was successfully annotated.

Comment: OK, I take it back. Everytime that I add a new model and subsequently execute "annotate", I get "Nothing annotated!" I cannot figure out why it works eventually, but not immediately. Any ideas?

Comment: We've seen the same thing happen, probably just an issue with latest Rails version.  It still annotates, but reports back that it didn't.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.  A few commands dont run right without the exec

bundle exec annotate